Basis for skew-symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables
I am reading from Introduction to Group Characters by Walter Ledermann [2nd edition]
On page $113$, the proposition $4.4$ states

The set $V=\{V_l\}$ where $l$ ranges over all strictly decreasing partitions of n, forms a basis of the skew-symmetric polynomials in n indeterminates

Here, $V_l$ denotes the $l-th$ alternant defined as the determinant of the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
x_1^{l_1} &x_1^{l_2} & \dots &x_1^{l_n} \\
x_2^{l_1} &x_2^{l_2} & \dots &x_2^{l_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
x_n^{l_1} &x_n^{l_2} & \dots &x_n^{l_n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Here, $l=(l_1,l_2,...l_n)$ is a strictly decreasing $n$-tuple
I see that this is clearly false as given by the simple $n=2$ case
As per the theorem, the basis only has a single element corresponding to the $l=(2)$ case which is $V_{(2)}=det\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & b^2 \\
a^0 & b^0
\end{vmatrix}=a^2-b^2$
Now $a^3-b^3$ is a skew symmetric polynomial in two variables which isn't in the span of our "basis"
I feel it should be changed to strictly decreasing $n$-tuples. But the thing that surprises me is that Ledermann continues using the fact that we require partitions of $n$ by repeatedly putting $|\lambda|=n$ under all of his summations in the discussion forward.
PS - When he says basis, he means it as a $\mathbb{C}$-basis and not over some other field
Here is an image of the relevant portion from the text


You are right when you say that a basis is given by partitions of length at most $n$. In perticular, the basis is infinite. However, I don't know this book and I don't have access to it, so I can't tell you if there is an actual error in the book or if you misunderstood something.

I think I should add some pics
